# Glassfish 3.1.2 configuration Client Certificate for Mutual Authentication

Tags: glassfish, client, certificate

I need help in configuring GF3.1.2 i have done following changes, please do let me know if i am missing anything important as after changes it is NOT working.
my id is nilesh2811@gmail.com

I could not found any particular thread or answers in forum if any link is there will be helpful.
if you have any document for this please forward.

please do the needful

web.xml

```xml
<login-config>
  <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <description/>
    <role-name>authorized</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
  <description/>
  <role-name>authorized</role-name>
</security-role>
```

sun-web.xml

```xml
<security-role-mapping>
  <role-name>authorized</role-name>
  <principal-name>admin</principal-name>
  <group-name>authorized</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

domain.xml

```xml
<security-service>
  <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm" name="admin-realm">
    <property name="file" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/admin-keyfile"></property>
    <property name="jaas-context" value="fileRealm"></property>
  </auth-realm>
  <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm" name="file">
    <property name="file" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keyfile"></property>
    <property name="jaas-context" value="fileRealm"></property>
  </auth-realm>
  <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm" name="certificate">
    <property name="assign-groups" value="authorized"></property>
  </auth-realm>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what "is NOT working". What kind of application are you building? Are you sure the client side is working correctly?

Comment: To be specific My borowser is not asking for client certificate, i want to authenticate user with client certificate, i have made specific changes in glassfish server.

Comment: so When i hit url in browser it should ask for client certificate? am i right.

Comment: Application:- JSF web application

Comment: web app is working smoothly end to end

Comment: I suggest building a test client which gives you much more control about what is going on. When I activated mutual authentication on a web service recently, the browser came up with an error page. But it is working fine when called from other clients.

Comment: I have browser based web apps, also I have comodo signed client certificate should i add that in to keystore.jks or cacerts.jks, also its root and intermediate certificate should go in to cacerts.jks??  please do let me know i think here it should be some mistake also same regarding server certificate i should install that in browser am i right

Comment: Web service client is working fine, is there any specific certificate exchange i have to do for browser based web application? Or browser is not sending certificate to server IE 8, and firefox i am using, server cert is glassfish pre installed, client cert is comodo secure email.

Comment: It is working with Web-browser also, I was using comodo/home pki certificates i have removed, used self signed/verisign client certificates, and now it is working proper this was Firs Time for me Client Authentication Few!!!

Answer (score 1):

The login-config section is incomplete in your web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>certificate</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

The realm-name content must match the name attribute of auth-realm element in domain.xml, which in your case is "certificate"

[updated]

In addition, the CA certificate must be imported in the server's truststore

```
${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks
```

Comment: The server's keystore contains the server certificate, not the client ones.

Comment: Hi to be specific after changes in domain.xml for client cert auth my application is not asking for client certificate to authenticate user login in browser it should ask for client certificate, i have added realm name in login-config also, how would i know my client certificate is needed via GF3.1.2, if you want config files please do let me know. how to share them with you.

Comment: Could you please clarify your last comment? What happened after you put the correct realm-name in login-config section?

Comment: After changes i am trying to debug ssl log in server.log, following are the lines come in logs, 
[#|2012-04-25T11:12:33.026-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=41;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|admin-thread-pool-4848(3), fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?|#]    Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false|#]

Comment: also i have two personal certificates in my browser store still while connecting it is not asking or prompting to select certificate for client authentication?

Comment: Please help urgent need, everything is working fine only client certs are not coming to server side or in logs, please help only client certs are not reflecting everythis else is happeing

Comment: INFO: http-thread-pool-8181(3)
INFO: , RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  
INFO: warning, 
INFO: no_certificate
INFO: SSL -- handshake alert:  no_certificate
INFO: http-thread-pool-8181(3), fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: no_certificate
INFO: %% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
INFO: http-thread-pool-8181(3)
INFO: , SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  
INFO: fatal, 
INFO: description = internal_error
INFO: http-thread-pool-8181(3), WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
INFO: Using SSLEngineImpl.

Comment: I have comodo signed client certificate should i add that in to keystore.jks or cacerts.jks, also its root and intermediate certificate should go in to cacerts.jks??  please do let me know i think here it should be some mistake also same regarding server certificate i should install that in browser am i right

Comment: Now i am trying to setup glassfish without any apps simple glassfish for client auth setup, https://localhost:8181/

Comment: Hand shake is happening smoothely when using with web service client, only when connecting via web browser certificate exchange is not happening, getting no-cert error when client is trying to present client cert, any suggestion how to exchange certs between web browser and server?

Comment: It is working with Web-browser also, I was using comodo/home pki certificates i have removed, used self signed/verisign client certificates, and now it is working proper this was Firs Time for me Client Authentication Few!!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I tries on glassfish 3.1.2 and it worked under following conditions:

1.I have to use the same key(trust) store of jks type and in the same location. In order to talk with other certificate formats you have to convert them to format jks format can handle.

2.in a glassfish-web.xml you should have like this mapping

```
    <security-role-mapping>
      <role-name>manager</role-name>   
    <group-name>authorized</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
```

3.in a domain.xml file   you should have the followings:

```
<auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm" name="certificate">
              <property name="assign-groups" value="authorized"></property>
            </auth-realm>
```

Note: in web.xml you have to have realm name matching domain.xml file

Comment: <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>certificate</realm-name>
  </login-config>

Comment: Thanks khurshed for taking time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

When anyone will try this first time it will take time for them to understand,  withing simple words, both client and server trust-stores should trust each other certificates, first it is better to use Self-signed certificates exchange certificates to server and client, one can use following article for help which has simplified steps. follow article then you can use your own methods certificates which ever u want.

http://www.slideshare.net/krizsan/scdjws-5-study-notes-3085287

SCDJWS 5
or nowadays know as
Oracle Certified Professional,
Java EE 5 Web Services Developer
Study Notes
by
Ivan A Krizsan
Version: February 23, 2012

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
Client Authentication: true
```

in `http-listener-2`.