# Tomcat + SNI + Mutual Authentication

Tags: tomcat, ssl, sni, mutual-authentication

I know that Tomcat provides both SNI and mutual authentication, but is it possible to enable MA only for selected applications/paths? I.e. let's say that I have the following applications/endpoints on my server:

```
/app1
/app2/human
/app2/robot
```

where **/app2/human** is used by humans and **/app2/robot** is used by robots, computers and other devices (so for example /app2/human serves HTML and /app2/robot serves JSON). Now, can I somehow configure Tomcat to accept connections to **/app1** and **/app2/human** via SSL without MA and to **/app2/robot** only if client presented valid certificate?

Of course I want to do it without configuring separate ports/connectors for each application, this is easy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't provide selective-mutual-authentication for different paths, but if you only need to have such selective-mutual-authentication apply at the webapp-level (and not inside of a particular web application), you might be able to get away with having a separate `<Connector>` for a special web application. This requires a separate `<Service>` and therefore `<Host>`, and of course a different port number (unless you happen to have a separate network interface you can use to preserve ports).

<s>I haven't tried it, but I would imagine that, theoretically, SNI+client-auth could be configured so that a particular hostname would have different client-authentication requirements, but there is no such code in Tomcat to support that currently.</s>

Tomcat can be configured to use a different trust store and a different `certificateVerification` setting per hostname, but it doesn't allow you to change it *per path*.

Another option would be to configure Tomcat to "want" (or even require) a client cert, and then perform the checking yourself using a `Filter`. `Filter`s can be applied on a per-path basis, plus your application becomes more portable because you aren't relying on some feature that may be Tomcat-specific.

Have a look at this thread for how I did this a few years ago. There is (eventually) some sample code plus lots of references for how I got all the information to put it together: http://markmail.org/thread/vxwwli5nzt4itfr2

Comment: I think the second connector is terrible overhead for a quite simple thing.
With all the nice stuff Mark Thomas has added with TLS virtual hosting in Tomcat 9, this is a really missing feature for those in need.

Comment: I guess only the guy who makes the commit gets any love :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765689/696632) and by reading the docs, you cannot have selective mutual auth on a per-path basis. It is all or nothing because client auth is configured at connector level. You are probably looking for [SSL renegotation with client auth](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ssl-profiles-part-6-ssl-renegotiation) which is probably not implemented as you might be used to from Apache HTTPd.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought looking at classes like SSLSocket, SSLSocketFactory and so on. It seems that it can be done by hand as it was written in the post you linked - set "wantClientAuth(true)" instead of "needClientAuth" and perform "manual" verification - in fact it seems that it is enough to check "((SSLSocket)socket).getSession().getPeerCertificates()" - if client isn't authenticated, it will throw an exception javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException which is enough to drop connection or return something meaningful.