# Mutual Auth on Glassfish, Connection Interrupted

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I have a Glassfish instance, 3.1.2.2, with 4 HTTP listeners. Here are the relevant data points:

- admin-listener : default admin 4848

  - Works fine
- http-listener-1 : default http 8080

  - Works fine
- http-listener-2 : ssl (server auth) 8181

  - Works fine
- http-listener-3 : ssl (mutual auth) 8282

  - Server cert is retrieved but then a the connection is 'interrupted' **no errors in the logs**

Obvious configuration info:

- keystore.jks has a self signed certificate with the correct CN (CN=ServerName), 'selfcert'.
- selfcert is the named certificate for both ssl listeners
- cacerts.jks has a copy of the client issued CA
- The web browser has a client certificate signed by the CA
- ports are open in the firewall
- Web Application is using SpringSecurity, the x509 tag, and has been successfully deployed on other platforms

I've scoured SO and the search engines to no avail. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: yes, I checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254610/glassfish-3-1-2-configuration-client-certificate-for-mutual-authentication but that seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue/bug[enter link description here](https://issues.connectopensource.org/browse/GATEWAY-3370) that was documented and will be addressed in Glassfish 4